# How to 2-step authenticate by password + U2F Yubikey in Linux KeePassX?

Tags: yubikey, fido-u2f, 2-factor-authentication, keepassx

I would like to have 2-step authentication by password + Fido U2F security key. 
I did not find any approaches which would work in Debian 8.7. 
The OS should not be a limiting factor here because Qt libraries are used with [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/).

OS: Debian 8.7
Fido U2F key: YubiKey Neo, YubiKey 4

Comment: I don't know exactly how U2F works, but in a sense it seems difficult (impossible) to require a one-time password / challenge-response authentication for a static file that's stored locally as you'd need some program to run the algorithm, and the file itself can't do that. It would need to be re-encrypted with a new key on every use, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

The only form of two-factor authentication supported in KeePassX is a password and a key-file; quoting the [features](https://www.keepassx.org/features):

> access to the KeePassX database is granted either with a password, a key-file (e.g. a CD or a memory-stick) or even both.

If you want to add U2F support you'll have to code it.

Comment: See the [forum](https://forum.keepassx.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4082).

Comment: The forum is not about the development. We managed to merge the ticket #52 to #127 10 hous ago. :) The developmentt is speeding up now. Please, see the open ticket where we need preview help.

Answer (score 0):

Development is going on

- Since 2014 active, but closed and merged now to #127: https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx/pull/52
- Add Yubikey 2FA for unlocking databases. https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/pull/127

I requested preview support for the ticket #52 from YubiKey support team with Ticket #00019088:

> We do not support this app. We do know that they have already added support for CR several years ago. As to supporting the developer in getting this working, if they reach out to us we are more than happy to work with them on this.

I passed the piece of information to the developer as a comment in the ticket. 
Now, #52 is finally merged to #127. 
I will look forward for the preview help in the latest ticket. 
I requested preview support from the YubiKey support team for the titket #127 now.

### KeePassX Dev

I am studying the project [supporting YubiKey DB unlock](https://dev.keepassx.org/issues/76) which can be about the case here.