# How to use Security Key in NordVPN login?

Tags: debian, openvpn, yubikey, fido-u2f

Situation: static password file in NordVPN settings
Proposal: any security key but proposed one, *YubiKey*, because big userbase

I heard that you can setup Security key (Fido U2F) with VPN in theory. 
I am thinking how to do it with NordVPN in practice. 
Their customer service says that they cannot do it at the moment, but state that it is possible in the following discussion.

> Unfortunately we are not aware if this would work with our service,
>   you would need to test this out for yourself.

### VPN files

Their default udp file looks like in `/etc/openvpn/fi1...udp...`

```
#           _   _               ___     ______  _   _
#          | \ | | ___  _ __ __| \ \   / /  _ \| \ | |
#          |  \| |/ _ \| '__/ _` |\ \ / /| |_) |  \| |
#          | |\  | (_) | | | (_| | \ V / |  __/| |\  |
#          |_| \_|\___/|_|  \__,_|  \_/  |_|   |_| \_|
#


client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 91.233.116.223 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0

remote-cert-tls server

#mute 10000
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt

comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
28c03f853cd7ec999b707d1eaa5296f4
7d315d8bc9657b22d3ca763d3d08f6ef
2d0d00115087d3832b53a85f4014a82b
0934baa25c37f14a8b114992ca6a0f9d
741b3ef40b1849fe859386d2556e738b
7d9b79369d49bc06cb12370e141408ce
4a738d9cd7463d4062263c7442394258
7a9172fe1732ceaf3fd69492283ce085
0a6e21111a39d4c3b28e2d6f7b406d2e
bccb965df0a1253fc78f88f7c27808be
64ac07535c671cebe971d603cecdaa17
ae89b7502ebac541c74d58b67cbf508e
7b22b34aa47b1b75971c8599205dff8b
7c0fbe363a0b5d64d8e7bafe88996d16
a7a767f15575885785f65dcd1a989c4d
4c1c34203d23bbc4000da626be7d7749
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Your password file at `/etc/openvpn/nordvpn.txt`

```
username@gmail.com
myStrongPassword
```

OS: Debian 8.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB
Security Keys: YubiKey 4, YubiKey Neo
NordVPN Ticket ID: #744897

Comment: There are a tuto here (http://www.mikejonesey.co.uk/security/2fa/openvpn-with-2fa) to set up openvpn with 2FA , maybe it will help you to set up  fido-u2f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official development project for the feature in NordVPN. 
A similar development project has been in KeePassX which has taken years in the thread [supporting YubiKey DB unlock](https://dev.keepassx.org/issues/76) which is discussed and/or organised also in the thread [How to 2-step authenticate by password + U2F Yubikey in Linux KeePassX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350473/how-to-2-step-authenticate-by-password-u2f-yubikey-in-linux-keepassx). 
I think it is much better to put resources on the completion of the KeePassx project before providing a similar feature in NordVPN login.